# How dynamic update v-combobox items list?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use v-combobox to search through the API, and I want to display hints in the drop-down list, the problem is that initially the array :items is empty, and when data comes from the API, the drop-down list does not open automatically, I have to repeatedly click on the input field to see the result

```
<script setup>
const inputValue = ref('')
const items = ref([])

watch(inputValue, async value => {
  const response = await fetch('...')
  items.value = await response.json()
})
</script>

<template>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="inputValue"
    :items="items"
  >   
  </v-combobox>
</template>
```

P.S: I could use v-textfield and v-menu, but then I won't be able to use the arrows on the keyboard to control the list.

Comment: the question is ambiguous; do you mean 1. the combobox should be opened(clicked) automatically when new data is fetched or 2. the combobox should should be updated but it is not?

Comment: @sungryeol, 
If the user has entered something in the input field for the first time, then the drop-down menu should open and show the API response, this drop-down menu should be updated as the user enters text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

### 1. use `<v-autocomplete />` instead of `<v-combobox />`

`<v-autocomplete />` is more appropriate for this sort of operation, as stated in [Vuetify official document](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#api-search):

> Easily hook up dynamic data and create a unique experience. The v-autocomplete’s expansive prop list makes it easy to fine tune every aspect of the input.
>
> (excerpt from v-combobox > API search)

### 2. trigger the query action from `v-on:focus`

```html
<!- v-model:search and v-model are both present
  to preserve manual user input ->
<v-autocomplete
  v-model:search="keyword"
  v-model="select"
  :items="items"
  @focus="() => query(keyword)" />
```

```js
// script
const query = async (_keyword: string) => {
  loading.value = true;
  const filteredLists = await fetchData(_keyword);
  items.value = filteredLists;
  loading.value = false;
};
```

### full code

```html
<template>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model:search="keyword"
      v-model="select"
      :items="items"
      :loading="loading"
      @focus="() => query(keyword)"
    />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { fetchData } from '@/lib/mockedApi';

const select = ref(null);
const keyword = ref('');
const items = ref<string[]>([]);
const loading = ref(false);
const query = async (_keyword: string) => {
  loading.value = true;
  const filteredLists = await fetchData(_keyword);
  items.value = filteredLists;
  loading.value = false;
};
watch(keyword, (v) => {
  query(v);
});
</script>
```

### edit

> I didn't use v-autocomplete because when the focus is lost, the value is reset there.

if the keyword(result) has to be independent of list value, just replace `<v-autocomplete />` with `<v-combobox />`.

The demo also has been updated accordingly. It includes demo for both combobox and autocomplete.

```html
<template>
    <v-combobox
      v-model:search="keyword"
      v-model="select"
      :items="items"
      :loading="loading"
      @focus="() => query(keyword)"
    />
</template>
```

working demo available on Github: https://github.com/rabelais88/stackoverflow-answers/tree/main/74980402-vuetify-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you! 
I didn't use v-autocomplete because when the focus is lost, the value is reset there.

Comment: @AinurYarulin I've updated the answer. Hope it helps.